# Where's the body?

Tags: fear-the-walking-dead

**Spoilers ahead**

So in the first episode of Fear The Walking Dead we see the first zombie (the girl) eating the face of a body. After all the things we see happen to the kid, his dad goes to the same place only to find a stain of blood.

If the zombie moved the body, then there would be stains from there to the location of the body, and the dad would have found it.
On the other hand if the zombie ate it all, then there would be bones remains, which there aren't.

So where did the body go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zombie attacks human, human dies and zombie eats some of human. Dead human (which did not suffer a traumatic enough brain injury to prevent reanimation) becomes zombie and stumbles off. It's been seen over and over again. Human dies, people leave, come back later and body is gone. Body is now a zombie who returns and chews their faces off. (Humans never learn.)

Comment: I've never seen a zombie waking up on another zombie eating it and fight it off. Where are these scenes?

Comment: Why would a zombie be attacking another zombie? I don't understand how you'd come to that conclusion. One was human, the other was zombie. The zombie kills the human, and the human becomes a zombie because of the infection.

Comment: Yes, but when the human becomes a zombie, he "wakes up" on a zombie eating the zombie. So would the zombie attack back on a "hey man, I'm a zombie, stop eating me" attempt or...?

Comment: Zombies don't eat other zombies. Historically once the zombie detects (via whatever method zombies have to discern their own kind from food) that a body is infected, they still stop eating the corpse. This is generally long before the body reanimates into a zombie.  I wish I could quote a medical journal for accuracy, but all I have to go on is a lifetime of zombie movie watching. :) Edit: you could say that when the body reanimates (before it actually wakes up) the body is no longer human, thus no longer food, so they stop eating.

Comment: Alright, I think I can buy that. :P

Comment: @Shoe - "A dead body wouldn't become a walker until its body temperature had lowered enough that another walker wouldn't be tempted to bite it. It reaches a very dead corpse state before reanimation occurs."
—Robert Kirkman, creator of TWD

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it became a zombie as well and wandered off to find food (e.g. humans). At least, that's what happens The Walking Dead and this takes place in the same universe.

Comment: I was under the impression that zombies did not eat zombies. So people killed by zombies would just get eaten. That's what happens with some of the characters in The Walking Dead series. Or at least it seems to me.

Comment: They don't - that body became a zombie through the act of being eaten on by the first zombie. Tim S. spelled out in more detail.